# Include external XML ENTITIES using SYSTEM while resolving path with $ENV variable

Tags: xml, unix, environment-variables, dtd

Looking at [some posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923273/can-entity-declarations-be-nested-in-referenced-xml-files?lq=1) and [others](http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/entity_declaration.shtml), I'm close to what I'm looking for, but not there yet.

**Overall goal**

To have XML ENTITY file**s** included within other XML file**s**, with the URI to SYSTEM taken from the an environment variable!

**Sample XML ENTITY files** (not sure if [xml declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085988/should-an-xml-file-included-via-entity-system-have-an-xml-declara) needed)

`$XML_PATH_SET_PER_ENV/entites/$CLIENT/entities.ent`

```
<!ENTITY COMPANY_ID "9800">
<!ENTITY PARENT_ID "98100">
<!ENTITY ACCOUNT_NAME "THE SUN PEOPLE">
<!ENTITY ACCOUNT_AB "TSP">
```

or `$XML_PATH_SET_PER_ENV/entites/$CLIENT/entities.ent`

```
<!ENTITY COMPANY_ID "7900">
<!ENTITY PARENT_ID "98500">
<!ENTITY ACCOUNT_NAME "FRUITS VEGGIES N MORE">
<!ENTITY ACCOUNT_AB "FVNM">
```

or `$XML_PATH_SET_PER_ENV/entites/$CLIENT/entities.ent`

```
<!ENTITY COMPANY_ID "84500">
<!ENTITY PARENT_ID "861675">
<!ENTITY ACCOUNT_NAME "THE SUN PEOPLE">
<!ENTITY ACCOUNT_AB "TSP">
```

Then within any XML file, I wish to *pull in* a specific `entities.ent` as needed:

doc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE TEST [

    <!ENTITY % get_em SYSTEM "entities.ent" >
    %get_em;

]>

<TEST>
        <COMPANY_ID>&COMPANY_ID;</COMPANY_ID>
</TEST>
```

However, before getting to my stated goal, I struggling first to get this simple `doc.xml` to work:

```
$ ls -lrt doc.xml entities.ent
-rw-r--r--. 1 user other 186 Dec 28 14:33 entities.ent
-rw-r--r--. 1 user other 182 Dec 28 14:34 doc.xml
```

And xmllint is not happy :(

```
$ xmllint --noout doc.xml
doc.xml:10: parser error : Entity 'COMPANY_ID' not defined
        <COMPANY_ID>&COMPANY_ID;</COMPANY_ID>
                                        ^
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the simple test to work, just need extra options to xmllint!

```
$ xmllint --loaddtd --noent --dropdtd doc.xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<TEST>
        <COMPANY_ID>84500</COMPANY_ID>
</TEST>
```

No errors!