# Make XML::Simple read external DTDs

Tags: xml, perl, dtd

Given the below two files:

**doc.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE TEST [

    <!ENTITY % get_em SYSTEM "entities.ent" >
    %get_em;

]>

<TEST>
        <COMPANY_ID>&COMPANY_ID;</COMPANY_ID>
</TEST>
```

**entities.ent**

```
<!ENTITY COMPANY_ID "84500">
<!ENTITY SPN_FIRM_ID "5900">
<!ENTITY SPN_CUSTD_REL_ID "40001">
<!ENTITY CUSTD_FIRM_NBR "229">
<!ENTITY CUSTD_FIRM_ID "5901">
<!ENTITY MASTERACCOUNT "TAL">
```

I can successfully use `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --loaddtd --noent --dropdtd doc.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TEST>
        <COMPANY_ID>84500</COMPANY_ID>
</TEST>
```

How could I get this idea to work in Perl and XML::Simple?

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -MXML::Simple -e 'print Dumper XMLin q{doc.xml}'
doc.xml:4: parser error : PEReference: %get_em; not found
    %get_em;
            ^
doc.xml:9: parser error : Entity 'COMPANY_ID' not defined
        <COMPANY_ID>&COMPANY_ID;</COMPANY_ID>
                                ^
```

After some comments, I've tried with `XML::LibXML::Simple` it does look a little better but the entity still does not get resolved

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -MXML::LibXML::Simple -e 'print Dumper XMLin q{doc.xml}'
./doc.xml:9: parser error : Entity 'COMPANY_ID' not defined
        <COMPANY_ID>&COMPANY_ID;</COMPANY_ID>
                                ^
```

Hmm and the `PEReference` of the above stands out .. what's `PE` ?
But more importantly, how can I get Perl with XML::Simple to read external DTD?

I tired `XML::Simple::DTDReader` but I find this module very restrictive especially it states [specifically](http://search.cpan.org/~alexmv/XML-Simple-DTDReader-0.04/DTDReader.pm#OPTIONS) that *none of `XML::Simple`'s myriad of options are supported*!

If I include the ENTITY declarations in the `doc.xml` itself it DOES work .. so obviously `XML::Simple` *knows* how to handle the `DOCTYPE` only I would like to use external DTD with `SYSTEM`, and that's where I'm stuck to get it to work.

Comment: Why not use a decent parser instead?

Comment: @ikegami The particular XML Configs, I'm dealing with are *simple* ! The only complexity I found with the current setup is there are many copies of same basic XML and just a couple of variables are changing. It the spirit of staying simple, I wish to introduce the concept of a variable by using XML ENTITY refs, and I hope to include them with `SYSTEM` thanks

Comment: What does that have to do with my question? If you want something simple, then run, [run far away from XML::Simple](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33267765/589924).

Comment: Here is why `XML::Simple` is a bad idea: [Why is XML::Simple discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged) - there are NO tasks that are made easier by using it, and plenty that are made MASSIVELY more complicated.

Comment: @Sobrique, your link is excellent, and I am and still am using it to convince my higher-ups, however, I happen to be dealing with a [dissenter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33285874/3299282)

Comment: What about `XML::LibXML::Simple` ? I edited the question showing that it does look a little better but does not solve my original intent .. thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML::LibXML will expand entities by default, so you can use

```
$ perl -e'
    use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );
    use XML::LibXML  qw( );
    use XML::Simple  qw( XMLin );

    my $xml = XML::LibXML->new()->parse_file("doc.xml")->toString();
    my $doc = XMLin($xml);
    print(Dumper($doc));
'
$VAR1 = {
          'COMPANY_ID' => '84500'
        };
```

This can also be achieved with XML::LibXML::Simple by overriding XML::Simple-compatibility settings.

```
$ perl -e'
    use Data::Dumper        qw( Dumper );
    use XML::LibXML::Simple qw( XMLin );

    my $doc = XMLin("doc.xml",
        ParserOpts => {
            load_ext_dtd    => 1,
            ext_ent_handler => undef,
        },
    );
    print(Dumper($doc));
'
$VAR1 = {
          'COMPANY_ID' => '84500'
        };
```

Comment: Nice! it works `perl -MData::Dumper -MXML::LibXML::Simple -e 'print Dumper XMLin (q{doc.xml}, ParserOpts => {load_ext_dtd  => 1, ext_ent_handler => undef})'` Thanks

Comment: Yeah, except you said you had to use XML::Simple... That's the worse of the possible solutions. Not only are you not using XML::Simple, your forcing another parser to produce the same broken output as XML::Simple

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking if this can be done within Perl itself, but a Simple way would be to combine what I found with [xmllint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34533250/3299282) and pass as file handle to [`XMLin`](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm#XMLin%28%29)!

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -MXML::Simple -e 'open my $fh, "xmllint --loaddtd --noent --dropdtd doc.xml |"; print Dumper XMLin $fh'
$VAR1 = {
          'COMPANY_ID' => '84500'
        };
```